# Parsing Solr Results - javabin format

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to integrate solr with java using solrj. The result retrieved are of the format

```
{
    numFound=3,
    start=0,
    docs=[
        SolrDocument{
            id=IW-02,
            name=iPod&iPodMiniUSB2.0Cable,
            manu=Belkin,
            manu_id_s=belkin,
            cat=[
                electronics,
                connector
            ],
            features=[
                carpoweradapterforiPod,
                white
            ],
            weight=2.0,
            price=11.5,
            price_c=11.50,
            USD,
            popularity=1,
            inStock=false,
            store=37.7752,
            -122.4232,
            manufacturedate_dt=TueFeb1418: 55: 59EST2006,
            _version_=1452625905160552448
        }
```

Now this is the javabin format. How do I extract results from this? Have heard that solrj does convert the results to objects by itself. But cant figure out how.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Where is problem located in? Did you check `SolrServer.query()` method?

Comment: I query solr using solrserver.query(). I have the result in query response object. My task is to parse the results and show it in GUI.

Comment: @AdityaSingla : You can take the data from the response object and copy it into your corresponding structure which you are using for GUI. Not sure about how it works in java, but I created a wrapper for a corresponding model, which I was using for the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let solrReply be the response object. The you can access different parts of the result using appropriate params. Say you want docs, you can do:

```
docs = solrReply['docs']
```

if you want the first result you could do:

```
first = solrReply['docs'][0]
```

Within a result you can access each field in the same way.